# How to change AppCompatDialog Typeface?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need to change typeface of message `TextView` and title `TextView` of alert dialog without setting a custom layout, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

Now you got the message `TextView` do whatever operation you can.